# Django ORM: filter by a list of objects

Tags: django, orm, filter

I have the following code to put all my users from a multichoice field into a list

```
USERS = []
for user in User.objects.filter(groups__name='accountexec'):
    USERS.append((user.id,user))
```

I need to use Log.objects.filter() to get all the logs with a user= to a user in the USERS list

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use the `__in` lookup:

```
Log.objects.filter(user__in=User.objects.filter(groups__name='accountexec'))
```

Comment: Actually, just "Log.objects.filter(user__in=User.objects.filter(groups__name='accountexec'))". Django will turn that into a single query + subquery.

Comment: Took the liberty of improving the suggested query according to James' suggestion, hope that's OK.